# Why ' ' doesn't work? "expected expression, empty character constant"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMLINES 6
void main(){
    int i, indent, howmany;
    void display(int,char);
    for(i = 1; i <= NUMLINES; i++){
        display(NUMLINES + 1 - i, '');
        display(2 * i - 1, '*');
        printf("\n");
       }
    }

void display (int howmany, char symbol){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= howmany; i++) printf("%c", symbol);
}
```

Error says "expected expression, empty character constant". Why ' ' doesn't work?

Comment: ````''```` is empty character which does not mean anything. Guess you want to pass a space for which you can try passing ````' '````

Comment: Please open a new question after you selected an answer. Do not edit it with a completely different meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `' '` (space) instead of `''` (empty) as the latter is not a valid character constant.  Here is how the standard defines it in section 6.4.4.4:

> character-constant:
> ’ c-char-sequence ’
> L’ c-char-sequence ’
> u’ c-char-sequence ’
> U’ c-char-sequence ’

> c-char-sequence:
> c-char
> c-char-sequence c-char

> c-char:
> any member of the source character set except
> the single-quote ’, backslash \ , or new-line character
> escape-sequence

Comment: oh thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work simply because the C syntax is (C17 6.4.4.4):

> `'` *c-char-sequence* `'`

Where "c-char-sequence" can't be left empty. So you have to write *something* there, such as for example a space character:

`' '`

Comment: Your answer prompted me to consult the standard and added the section numbers for good measure.